# Carbon date format 'd/m/Y h:i A'

Tags: php, momentjs, php-carbon

I am trying to convert a date I got from moment.js to carbon object
moment.js format:

```
format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm A'
```

however I am getting an error

> The format separator does not match Data missing

Here is my code:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('29/09/2017 00:23 AM', 'd/m/Y h:i A');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It's the other way around: `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', '29/09/2017 00:23 AM');`

Comment: damn!!! thanks man

Answer (score 0):

The format is wrong.

Try this `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', '29/09/2017 00:23 AM');`

This should be the format `Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);`

See documentation [Carbon documentation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)